# Вывод всей таблицы из MySQL с оформлением

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Помогите мне Вывести всю таблицу из MySQL с оформлением, ну или расскажите мне как это возможно,
Например в таблице 13 строк ну и на сайте тоже 13 а при добавлении через PHPMyAdmin 1 строки на сайте тоже добавлялась 1 стока

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- заходим в phpmyadmin  -> экспорт таблицы
- копируем sql код
- идем сюда -> http://www.phpscaffold.com
- вставляем sql код
- удаляем из начала if not exist
- жмем make my pages
- получаем код
- разбираем его
- радуемся жизни:)